# SetAlarmClock() на Xiaomi

Tags: android-alarm-manager, xiaomi

Проверенный пример использования SetAlarmClock(), который будет работать на мобильных устройствах от Xiaomi.

Я тестировал на своём Redmi X5, будильник срабатывает только когда приложение открыто и не свёрнуто. Значок будильника в трее (шторка сверху) не появляется. Разрешения в манифесте присутствуют. На эмуляторе всё работает как надо.